# What are the method parameters of Java's Timer#schedule

Tags: java, timer, jframe, jpanel, schedule

I'm currently trying to use a `Timer` to execute an action at set intervals.

I've taken a snippet from Stack Overflow, however it did not have an explanation, and I'm struggling to figure out what it's parameters mean.

Could someone please explain to me the parameters for the method?
It's namely the last 2 parameters, `5000, 5000` which I don't understand.

```java
TimerTask damageInterval = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        playerInfoPanel.health -= monsterDamage - playerInfoPanel.defenceLevel;
    }
};
            

inflictDamage.schedule(damageInterval, 5000, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JavaDocs are your friend](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

> ```
> public void schedule(TimerTask task,
>                      long delay,
>                      long period)
> ```
>
> Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution,
>   beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place
>   at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period.
>
> In fixed-delay execution, each execution is scheduled relative to the
>   actual execution time of the previous execution. If an execution is
>   delayed for any reason (such as garbage collection or other background
>   activity), subsequent executions will be delayed as well. In the long
>   run, the frequency of execution will generally be slightly lower than
>   the reciprocal of the specified period (assuming the system clock
>   underlying Object.wait(long) is accurate).
>
> Fixed-delay execution is appropriate for recurring activities that
>   require "smoothness." In other words, it is appropriate for activities
>   where it is more important to keep the frequency accurate in the short
>   run than in the long run. This includes most animation tasks, such as
>   blinking a cursor at regular intervals. It also includes tasks wherein
>   regular activity is performed in response to human input, such as
>   automatically repeating a character as long as a key is held down.
>
> **Parameters:**
>  `task` - task to be scheduled.
>  `delay` - delay in milliseconds before task is to be executed. period - time in
>   milliseconds between successive task executions.